# Error during training of Convolutional Neural Network using TensorFlow on Google Colab: "Cudnn graph failed to build: UNKNOWN: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM"

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, cudnn

### I am trying to train a Convolutional Neural Network using TensorFlow 2.12.0 on Google Colab. However, I am running into an error during the training phase of the model. The error I am encountering is:
Epoch 1/15

> InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-24-b02ccbf8b5af> in <cell line: 5>()
> 3
> 4 # Train your model
> 5 history = model.fit(train_generator,
> 6                     epochs=15,
> 7                     validation_data=validation_generator)
>
> ...
> InternalError: Graph execution error:
>
> Detected at node 'sequential_4/conv2d_8/Relu' defined at (most recent call last):
> ...
>
> Cudnn graph failed to build: UNKNOWN: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
> in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3760): 'conv_op' CUDNN_BACKEND_OPERATION: cudnnFinalize Failed
> [[{{node sequential_4/conv2d_8/Relu}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4999]
> The error message suggests an issue with CUDA/CuDNN ("Cudnn graph failed to build: UNKNOWN: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM") while executing the activation function for my convolutional layer ('conv2d_2/Relu').

Here are relevant code snippets:

```
    def train_val_generators(training_images, training_labels, validation_images, validation_labels):
    ...
    return train_generator, validation_generator
```

```
    def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(\[
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(26, activation='softmax')
    \])


    model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop',
    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=\['accuracy'\])  
    return model
```

````
```model = create_model()
history = model.fit(train_generator,
epochs=15,
validation_data=validation_generator)
````

```
The environment I am working with includes TensorFlow version: 2.12.0 and CUDA version: 11.8 on Google Colab.

I have tried the following:

Verifying the TensorFlow, CUDA, and CuDNN versions
Reducing the batch size
Checking the model architecture
Ensuring I'm using the GPU in Colab
However, none of these solutions have helped. Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how I could potentially solve it? Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Hi @Francesco Boccardo, Could you please tell how the dataset look like, what is the type of dataset, how you are preprocessing the dataset? so that it will be helpful to understand the issue better.